# select query in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I try to select the data from the table product, but  "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM product " error is found

```
public Cursor getproduct(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = null;
    try{
        cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM product",new String [] {});
        cur.moveToFirst();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cur;
}
```

Comment: you need to show your `onCreate()` code of your Database class

Comment: Just simple write rawQuery like `cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM product");` As you did not specify any specific column.

Comment: you have onCreate inside your productDB  class ?

Comment: I'd recommend using [greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/) for database-creation and access. It definitly speeds up development and prevents typos in simple queries.

Comment: i create the database using sqlite studio and i just use the db in this application

Comment: Just recheck if the name of the table in the db is the same as the one in the sqlite query. or if the db is copied into the data/data folder correctly if reading from there

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use static references to e.g. the table name to not make any mistake in this. And the onCreate()-method for your table (as to what also the others are referring) shoudl look somehow like this:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "FodoSubstitutes.db";
private static String FOOD_TABLE = "Food";

//Creates the database with db name and calls onCreate(). 
public DbHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    //System.out.println("in onCreate");
    //assocID   food    healthierFood category  description count submittedBy
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + FOOD_TABLE +
                "(Food_ID integer primary key, " + 
                "Food_Name string not null, " +
                "Food_Aliases string, " + 
                "Hints string, " +
                "Category string, " + 
                "Subcategory string, " +
                "Description string, " + 
                "Submission_ID int, " +
                "Comment_ID int, " + 
                "Count int); ";
   db.execSQL(sql);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the getReadableDatabase() method doesn't return the database you want. You need to either build it inside your application or bundle it with the application (using Assets). The following are the code snippets to do both things:

**BUILDING A DATABASE**

```
    static final string DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + "product " + "(" +
    TABLE_COLUMN_1 + " " + COLUMN_1_TYPE + ", " + 
    TABLE_COLUMN_2 + " " + COLUMN_2_TYPE + ", "; //and so on
    public class MySQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, YOUR_DATABASE_NAME, null, YOUR_DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       try {
           db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
       }
       catch(SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

**USING ASSETS TO COPY A PRE-BUILT DATABASE**

First, you need to place your SQL file inside the assets folder of your application. Then put this code inside the onCreate() method of your main activity:

```
File f = new File(this.getDatabasePath().getAbsolutePath() + "/mydatabase.db";
if(!f.exists()) {
   if(f.getParentFile().exists() || f.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
       f.createNewFile();
       InputStream inputStream = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydatabase.db");
       OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int length;
       while((length = dbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
       }
       inputStream.close();
       outputStream.flush();
       outputStraem.close();
    }
    else
       throw new IOException("Database input error");
    }
}
```

This is using an assumption that the prebuilt database is placed in a "mydatabase.db" file.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some mistake in table name you are writing in your query,table name might be misspelled.